# How to read variables found by RegEx Extractor in Debug Sampler in jMeter

Tags: http, jmeter, performance-testing

## Problem Descryption

Im reading some variables with Regular Expression Extractor and some from .csv file.

All of theme are also defined in User Defined Variables. 
To see if the variable are taken correctly im using Debug Sampler.

As a result i received list of all variables but:

- every variable from regEx extractor looks like: ${variable},
- opposite to variables from csv file where i can see exactly whats is under this variable.

[image: Photo of my debug sampler:]

## Question

**Is it possible to see real value of the variable found by regular expression?**

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 2):

Your Regular Expression Extractor configuration is not correct. You should be providing the "Name of created variable" as "plain text", i.e. `id_token`, not `${id_token}`

If your Regular Expression Extractor will have match(es) - the variable, you define prior to that will be **overwritten**

Demo:

1. [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)

   [image]
2. [Regular Expression Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor)

   [image]
3. [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) before the Regular Expression Extractor

   [image]
4. JMeter Variables after the Regular Expression Extractor:

   [image]
5. The [Dummy Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeters-dummy-sampler-the-ultimate-guide/) which was used for illustrative demonstration purposes just in case:

   [image]

Answer (score 1):

Just **don't** define in  [User Defined Variables](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables)  variables from regEx extractor which have dynamic nature

> User Defined Variables element lets you define an **initial set of variables**